# Programmatically pasting into an iPhone UITextView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview, uipasteboard

I have an iPhone app with a `UITextView`. I'd like to be able to paste the clipboard contents into it without showing the `UIMenuController`.

I tried calling the `paste:` method on the `UITextView`, and on the first responder, but neither of those things worked.

I was able to implement this by writing a bunch of code to read text from the clipboard, insert it in the UITextView's `text` property, and update the selection range. I also added support for undo/redo. But it seems like there ought to be an easier way. Is there?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `paste` with `nil` sender?

```
[theTextView paste:nil];
```

as per [UIResponder docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/paste%3a)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try making the UITextView the first responder?

Comment: Yes, did that, and keyboard was visible.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the headers to the UITextView object, but I couldn't find any documented method called -paste; also, looking over the NSPasteboard class suggests to me that programatically setting your text was the right way to go.

If pasting text is important to your app, I would consider setting up a class to handle it; maybe even make it a singleton if it was important enough.

Good luck!

Comment: `paste:` is documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/paste%3a